# Solr conditional query fields (qf)

Tags: search, solr, lucene, edismax, solr-query-syntax

Is it possible to define query fields in Solr based on certain conditions? For e.g. I've three fields text, title and product.The solr config definition:

```
<str name="qf">text^0.5 title^10.0 Product</str>
```

What I'm looking here is to include "product" as a searchable field only when certain condition is met, for e.g. if author:"Tom", then search in Product as well.

Is there a way to do that during query time using edismax ?

The alternate I've is to add the product information to either text or title of the document (where author=Tom) during index time so it'll be searchable. But, I'm trying to avoid this if possible.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to search in different fields based on different conditions, there is a need to first search for that specific conditions, thus it is more or less the same as issuing multiple queries.

---

That said, in case there is a need to do it as a one-time query (e.g. for out-of-the-box sorting/grouping/other solr features), the [nested queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-NestedQueryParser) can be used.

For defining two different conditions (as in the original question, but it can easily be extended with more OR clauses), the `q` parameter can receive following value:

```
_query_:"{!edismax fq=$fq1 qf=$qf1 v=$condQuery}"
OR
_query_:"{!edismax fq=$fq2 qf=$qf2 v=$condQuery}"
```

The query uses [Parameter Dereferencing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Local+Parameters+in+Queries#LocalParametersinQueries-ParameterDereferencing), so there is no need to manually escape any special characters before passing the parameters to solr.

- **fq1** - first special condition
- **qf1** - list of fields to search in for first special condition (**fq1**)
- **fq2** - second special condition
- **qf2** - list of fields to search in for first special condition (**fq2**)
- **condQuery** - the actual search term/query

The **fq1** may be empty in order to define a baseline (in this particular case - search in `text` and `title`, but not in `product`).

The raw parameters themselves will look the following way:

```
fq1=&qf1=text^0.5 title^10.0&fq2=author:"Tom"&qf2=text^0.5 title^10.0 Product&condQuery=5
```

And the Final query will be something like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=_query_%3A%22%7B!edismax+fq%3D%24fq1+qf%3D%24qf1+v%3D%24condQuery%7D%22+OR+_query_%3A%22%7B!edismax+fq%3D%24fq2+qf%3D%24qf2+v%3D%24condQuery%7D%22&fl=*%2Cscore&wt=xml&indent=true&fq1=&qf1=text^0.5%20title^10.0&fq2=author:%22Tom%22&qf2=text^0.5%20title^10.0%20Product&condQuery=5
```

.. or the same query returned by solr in solr response (provided only for showing it in a structured way):

```xml
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="q">_query_:"{!edismax fq=$fq1 qf=$qf1 v=$condQuery}" OR _query_:"{!edismax fq=$fq2 qf=$qf2 v=$condQuery}"</str>
            <str name="condQuery">5</str>
            <str name="indent">true</str>
            <str name="fl">*,score</str>
            <str name="fq1"/>
            <str name="qf1">text^0.5 title^10.0</str>
            <str name="fq2">author:"Tom"</str>
            <str name="qf2">text^0.5 title^10.0 Product</str>
            <str name="wt">xml</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="..." start="..." maxScore="...">
        ...
    </result>
</response>
```

---

Even though it works, I suggest to consider the effect it would have on query time (as each condition will have a separate internal search query) and measure how it affects your specific case.

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to figure out how to implement this!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it by myself, but it looks like this could be achievable by using http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Boolean_Functions

Comment: Thanks Mysterion, I did try using boolean functions, but haven't been successful yet.

Answer (score 0):

Shamik,

I don't think there is a way to do this in Solr that is easy. One thing to consider is managing of these rules overtime too, it would be a nightmare for a large system.

If you really wanted to do something like this, maybe you can issue two calls to Solr to get the result set.